# Fundamental doubt on substitution method of integration

Tags: integration

Consider $\int_{-1}^1 x^2 dx$. If we substitute $x^2-1=t$, then the integral will become $\int_0^0\sqrt{t+1} dt/2$. So the second integral equals zero, but the first one is not zero. Which step in this process is wrong?

Comment: A substitution should be one to one: each value of $x$ in $[-1,1]$ should correspond with a unique value of $t$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

from the substitution we have that:

$
x=\sqrt{t+1} \quad $ for $\quad x\ge 0
$

$x=-\sqrt{t+1} \quad $ for $\quad x< 0$

so the starting integral split in two integrals after the substitution.

---

Added:

from $x^2-1=t$ we have:
$$
2x dx = dt \quad \rightarrow \quad dx=\frac{dt}{2x}
$$
that is

$dx=\frac{dt}{-2\sqrt{t+1}} $ for $x<0$

$dx=\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t+1}} $ for $x\ge 0$

and we have:
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} x^2 dx=\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{\sqrt{t+1}}{2}dt+\int_{0}^{-1}\frac{-\sqrt{t+1}}{2}dt=\int_{-1}^{0}\sqrt{t+1}dt
$$

Answer (score 0):

Right, the integration on $t$ is from $0$ to $0$. But *via* $-1$, and with a change of sign of $dt$ because $t$ decreases then increases.

Hence,

$$-\frac12\int_0^{-1}\sqrt{t+1}\,dt+\frac12\int_{-1}^0\sqrt{t+1}\,dt=\int_{-1}^0\sqrt{t+1}\,dt=\left.\frac{2(t+1)^{3/2}}3\right|_{-1}^0=\frac23.$$